# How to attach numbers from filename to front of csv using AWK

Tags: unix, awk

I want to use the awk command to attach all numbers from a filename to the front of a csv file.

At the moment I'm using the code below to attach just the filename to the front of the csv file but I'd like to add all number from the string before the filename.

```
awk '{print "\"" FILENAME "\"," $0}' filename_1.csv >> filename_2.csv
```

Can someone help me please?

Example of filename_1.csv

```
name,id,color
fred,1,blue
james,2,green
tom,3,purple
```

Expected output:

```
1,filename_1.csv,name,id,color
1,filename_1.csv,fred,1,blue
1,filename_1.csv,james,2,green
1,filename_1.csv,tom,3,purple
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please, give a sample file, filename and the expected output.

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{                # first record
    match(FILENAME,/[0-9]+/)  # search for the first string of numbers 
}{                            # if found, print numbers, filename and record:
    print (RSTART?substr(FILENAME,RSTART,RLENGTH) ",":"") FILENAME "," $0
}' filename_1.csv
```

Output:

```
1,filename_1.csv,name,id,color
1,filename_1.csv,fred,1,blue
1,filename_1.csv,james,2,green
1,filename_1.csv,tom,3,purple
```

If there is no numbers in the filename, don't print them, for example output for file `foo`:

```
foo,name,id,color
foo,fred,1,blue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} FNR==1 {fn=FILENAME; split(fn, a, /[_.]/); n = a[2]} { print n, fn, $0 }' filename_1.csv 
1,filename_1.csv,name,id,color
1,filename_1.csv,fred,1,blue
1,filename_1.csv,james,2,green
1,filename_1.csv,tom,3,purple
```